# how to make a resizable widget that can resized by the user

Tags: pyqt, pyside

I have a QHBoxLayout, and it has 2 QVBoxLayouts on it one near the other. 
Each layout has widgets, and I wonder how to make this layout resizable (the user can change the width) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [QSplitter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html). Create a couple of top-level container widgets for your vbox layouts, and then use the splitter's [addWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html#addWidget) method to add the widgets to the splitter. The splitter's orientation is horizontal by default, so the vboxes will appear side by side.